# SOAP run failed

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I have bellow code for SOAP

```
from spyne import ServiceBase, Application, rpc, Integer, String
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

class OddOrEvenService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Integer, _returns=String)
    def oddOrEven(self, num):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return "even"
        else:
            return "odd"
 

application = Application([OddOrEvenService], 'my.soap.app',
        in_protocol=Soap11(),
        out_protocol=Soap11(),
    )

wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 7789, wsgi_app)

print ("listening to http://127.0.0.1:7789")
print ("wsdl is at: http://localhost:7789/?wsdl")

server.serve_forever()
```

When I'm trying to run code I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Studii IT\Cursuri\First_SOAP_project.py", line 1, in <module>
from spyne import ServiceBase, Application, rpc, Integer, String
File"C:\Users\Enter83\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\spyne\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>    
from spyne.evmgr import EventManager
File "C:\Users\Enter83\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\spyne\evmgr.py", line 21, in <module>   
from spyne.util.oset import oset
File "C:\Users\Enter 83\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\spyne\util\oset.py", line 3, in <module>
from spyne.util.six.moves.collections_abc import MutableSet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyne.util.six.moves'
```

How is the solution of this error. Please help

I'll tried to install spyne once again but it does not work.

Comment: @OCa I have edited my code. Could you please help. 

Thank you

Comment: Maybe please describe steps you took to install spyne again. What you use to run the programm. To make qusetion clearer, remove all code except the line with problem, i.e. first import line. Split it in 4 imports to pinpoint what is missing? Add tags *installation* and *import*? I am sorry I am not knowledgeable in this.

Comment: What version is your spyne module now compared to newest in https://pypi.org/project/spyne/

Answer (score 0):

To create a SOAP request or response, you typically use XML. Below, I'll provide a simple example of a SOAP request and response in XML format. Keep in mind that in practice, you'd use a programming language or library to create and parse SOAP messages, but this is a manual XML representation for illustration purposes.

A SOAP request typically consists of an XML envelope with a  element containing the actual request data. Here's a simple example of a SOAP request:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
    xmlns:web="http://www.example.com/webservice">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:ExampleRequest>
            <web:Parameter1>Value1</web:Parameter1>
            <web:Parameter2>Value2</web:Parameter2>
        </web:ExampleRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: ok maybe, but how is this attempting to solve OP's problem, which seems to be at the installation and import phase already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm changed my python version 3.12.0 to 3.10.10 and ...
I can run it!